# How to Track Changes with jexcelapi or Apache HSSF

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi, jexcelapi

I am writing an MS Excel file with Java and what to set the "Track Changes" flag so I can see where people make modifications later. How can I set this flag in either jexcelapi or Apache HSSF?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think JExcelAPI supports that feature. Would it be viable for you to set up an Excel workbook with the option set, and then use that existing file as a template, instead of creating a new workbook from scratch?

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work because jexcelapi don't want to copy my template but throws some assertion-exception.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Workbook.getWorkbook(java.io.File file) should open an existing file for writing.